# Proposed Synonym: Intonation => Pitch Accent

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/pitch-accent/synonyms

Considering 4 out of 5 questions deal with it directly/also include it, it seems to make sense to fold the two together.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Intonation and pitch accent are different.  Accent marks the presence of a large phonemic drop in pitch.  You can ask a question with rising intonation, but this doesn't change the word's accent.  Some particles have different meaning with different intonation, but again this is not a matter of pitch accent.

I'm against making tags for two distinct concepts into synonyms.  Instead, we should try to use each tag when appropriate.

Comment: I agree. Maybe I'm simplifying but isn't it a bit like that: accent is used to describe variations within words (or maybe phrases, e.g. word + particle) that have grammatical or lexical meaning. Intonation doesn't distinguish words, it's used to give additional meaning to the whole message (e.g. making it a question or showing emotions).